# Where would the songs imported from Dance Central 2 to 3 go?

Tags: dance-central-2, dance-central-3

I went through the process of importing Dance Central 2 songs into Dance Central 3, but I don't see the songs anywhere.  How can I confirm they were actually added? Where and what should I see?

Comment: I asked on their forums recently: http://www.dancecentral.com/forums/showthread.php?t=11453&p=37776#post37776

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble with importing the DC2 songs into DC3.  Although it accepted my code, once it finished downloading the key it just left me hanging with no further instructions, and the songs didn't appear.

What I discovered my problem to be was that I had entered the code while signed into my son's account, which was set up so as to not have permission to buy content and which also didn't have any Microsoft coins associated with it.  When I changed those settings and added coins to his account, and then re-entered the code, it finally gave me the option to purchase the import pack after the download completed.  (I did have to re-enter the code -- simply re-downloading the key didn't work.)  I authorized the purchase, the songs downloaded smoothly, and they showed up in the game once the download was completed.

So apparently when I had initially entered the code, even though it apparently had been accepted, it hadn't really taken and what had downloaded wasn't really a functional key.  It would have been much more helpful to instead get an error message along the lines of "This is a correct code but the game cannot accept it because your account is not authorized to make purchases."

Answer (score 0):

I was able to restart the download from the xbox live online UI.  Gamertag download history, here: https://live.xbox.com/en-US/Download/History